# Fine Tuned Universe

Tags: cosmology, standard-model, physical-constants, anthropic-principle, fine-tuning

Is the fine tuning that cosmologists talk about (that our Universe is fine tuned for intelligent life) is the same as the fine tuning of the squared mass parameter of the Higgs in the Standard Model? And that in SUSY models?

Also, could anyone refer me to a source that explains the fine tuning issue in general?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument for fine tuning is far broader than just the Higgs. For example it's argued that the existance of any elements heavier than lithium relies on a fine tuned resonance in the carbon 12 nuclues that allows three helium nuclei to stay together long enough to form a carbon nucleus.

There are lots of books that explore these ideas. A good start would be Just Six Numbers, [http://www.amazon.com/Just-Six-Numbers-Forces-Universe/dp/0465036732](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465036732), by Martin Rees. If you want something a bit meatier try http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.4647 and references therein.

Comment: Thanks John for explaining and for the references. Now I'll get busy reading to gain more understanding of the issue.